# if I do the same with UIViewController instead of UIView then it works perfectly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, delegates

First loads a `UIView` from a `UIViewController`

```
myView *bso =[[myView alloc] init];
bso.assignProperty = object;
[self.view addSubview:bso];
```

myView.m

```
-(id) init{
    return [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyXib" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

when click in a button of UIView the property is nil

```
- (IBAction)click:(id)sender{
    self.assignProperty // always is nil
}
```

if I do the same with `UIViewController` instead of `UIView` then it works perfectly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be returning that from `init`; try:

```
-(id) init{
if ((self = [super init])) {
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyXib" owner:self options:nil];
}
return self;
}
```

Or alternatively remove the `init` method from `myView` and instead of your top code, do:

```
myView *bso = nil;
NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyXib" owner:self options:nil];
for (id o in nib) {
  if ([o isKindOfClass:[myView class]]) {
    bso = o;
    break;
  }
}
if (bso) {
  bso.assignProperty = object;
  [self.view addSubview:bso];
} else {
  NSLog(@"ERROR: Could not load bso!");
}
```

Also note that calling your class `myView` is confusing - Obj-C programmers expect classes to start with a Capital Letter.

Comment: If I not returns `[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyXib" owner:self options:nil];` not load the xib. The problem is when click in a IBAction from UIView